# SystemD service script will work on Systemctl start {service script} but not on reboot

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd

I am trying to right a systemd service script to perform a task on reboot. Below is the script and it works when I run 'systemctl start script.service but not when I reboot the system.

```
[Unit]
Description=put cloudify in maintenance mode on shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/cfy maintenance-mode activate
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target
```

I have performed:
systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl enable script.service

What that command will do is put an application into maintenance mode.

all services on the vm that are needed for this are also enabled.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the service just before your system reboots.  You need to add this dependency to your service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=put cloudify in maintenance mode on shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
After=final.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/cfy maintenance-mode activate
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=final.target
```